# Live Memory not matching Core Dumped Memory

Tags: java, memory, corruption, memory-corruption

We're trying to investigate memory corruption on an application and the exact issue we're seeing can be seen in the live memory of the application (i.e. debug code which has been added displays the corrupted information), however when we look through the core dumps which get taken at this point the data doesn't have the corruption.

From my rudimentary understanding of the core dump process this could be due to the OS flushing every buffer, finishing off partial writes and so on.

Can anyone go into detail on exactly what occurs and if there's anyway to determine what is causing the corruption?

mprotect() blocks all writes, not just non owning processes and this is data which has a lot of R/W access by our application (and is only have problems on new machines)

Comment: Are the dumps from exactly the same executable as the debug code, or a different release version?

Comment: Exactly the same, it's a Websphere application running on Java

Comment: Oh, you're probably going to have to give more environment details then, as Java code cannot create memory corruption on its own.

Comment: I know that, we're thinking it's a problem with memory "sync" on the machine, that things aren't getting flushed correctly, but trying to prove that is the bit I need help with.  It's a Linux OS running on new Dell R710 hardware

Comment: That's highly unlikely. Memory corruption is also pretty unlikely unless you're using JNI in your code. In rough order of likelihood: your Java code is wrong; a configuration issue; you misunderstood an API; a networking issue; there's a bug in Websphere; there's a bug in your JVM; there's a bug in your OS; you need a refund on your hardware.

Comment: Turned out to be RHEL4 and the Kernel it was running on, customer upgraded to RHEL5 with the latest Kernel and the problem vanished

Comment: DougEdey: Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be RHEL4 and the Kernel it was running on, customer upgraded to RHEL5 with the latest Kernel and the problem vanished